# What Motorola Bar Code Scanner Development Options are there?

Tags: barcode-scanner

I have been asked to investigate the possibility of developing software for a Motorola bar code scanner. From my initial searches it would appear that the only options are to code 'from the ground up' using Visual Studio or to use MCL-Designer, a RAD tool. Is this the case or are there other RAD tools available?

The project is really very simple & I'm surprised it is not something that is available out of the box on the scanner (maybe it is, I am open to correction). All that needs to be done is for the scanner to pick up a CSV file containing code to text translations (so that the person doing the scanning can confirm the device has scanned the correct code), keep a list of the codes scanned and associated quantities, then, when the session is complete, download the list to a PC. As I've said, if this application is already available then someone pointing me in the right direction to a datasheet or similar would be appreciated.

Comment: I'm also looking into something similar.  Did you ever find an answer to this?

Comment: @anon. Sorry, no, the project did not happen in the end so I did not go any further.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to configure your scanner to use USB HID (POS) instead of USB HID (Keyboard) by simply scanning a barcode settings from the manual for the device. Then download and play with the sample project from http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/18099/A-USB-HID-Component-for-C.